# Add in integer to returned value with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a page with a `div id="videoFrame"` that holds the video tag.  The videos have variable heights so I have a function to grab the height value and plug it into the css of the `div id="videoFrame"` like so:

```
var videoHeight = $('video').attr('height');
$('#videoFrame').css('height',videoHeight+'px');
```

This works great.  But here's the part driving me crazy.  I have a p tag with disclaimers at the bottom of the `div id="videoFrame"`.  So I would like to add an additional 26px to the returned height.  I tried:

```
var videoHeight = $('video').attr('height');
var frameHeight = videoHeight + 26;
$('#videoFrame').css('height',frameHeight+'px');
```

But as you would expect it is adding 26 to the end of the returned value. i.e. if returned value is 337 output for var `frameHeight` is 33726.

I can not for the life of me figure out how to do this.

Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$('video').attr('height')` returns a string.  Adding a number to a string converts the number to a string and adds the two strings which is not what you want.  You want to add two numbers.  So, you must convert this string to a number so you can then add two numbers:

```
var videoHeight = parseInt($('video').attr('height'), 10);
var frameHeight = videoHeight + 26;
```

There are a several ways to convert a string to a number.  Here are a few of the more obvious ones.

```
parseInt(str, radix)
parseFloat(str)
Number(str)
```

When using `parseInt`, always specify the radix, otherwise, it will guess based on the content of the string (which you almost never want).

Comment: Works!! Thank you for the help, and the explanation.  It's always better if you know why and not just how.

Answer (score 1):

ParseInt before you add.

`var frameHeight = parseInt(videoHeight) + 26;`

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

`var frameHeight = Number(videoHeight) + 26;`

Answer (score 0):

you should wrap parseInt() around the videoHeight variable.  try that, i hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `parseInt`

```
var videoHeight = parseInt($('video').attr('height'));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var frameHeight = parseInt(videoHeight,10) + 26;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var videoHeight = parseInt($('video').attr('height'));
var frameHeight = videoHeight + 26;
```